# Launch Emacsclient in ansi-terminal mode?

Tags: ansi-term

I connect to an emacs server via `emacsclient`. Frequently the first thing I want open is a *new buffer* with an `ansi-terminal` in it.

Is there a way to launch `emacsclient` and to send the command "open a new buffer with an ansi-terminal"?

**EDIT:** Or better yet, is there a way to launch emacsclient with the command "if a buffer is already open with ansi-terminal, then go to that buffer; otherwise, launch ansi-terminal in a new window"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will launch emacs client with a new ansi-term:

```
emacsclient -c -a emacs -q --eval "(ansi-term \"/bin/bash\")"
```

If you have ansi-term already open why not just switch to that buffer?

If you really wanted to you can write a small lisp function to check if the buffer exists using *(get-buffer name)* otherwise open ansi-term. Then simply call that function in the eval statement above.

```
(if (get-buffer "*ansi-term*") 
   (switch-to-buffer "*ansi-term*")
  (ansi-term "/bin/bash"))
```